# How can we log out a Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

We use Azure to obtain user credentials and they are stored in session. When logout is pressed. we Run the following:

```
if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
    Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
}
```

The user is then presented with this screen [image]

To be truly signed out the user has to select the account that they want to sign out of. Is there anyway that I can extend my code above to bypass this screen and just log all accounts out that may be present.

Comment: This has nothing *at all* to do with MFA. You're asking how to log out the user from any other site they've logged on with their Microsoft account. That's not *your* account or your site. You don't have the right to log out the user from eg Microsoft.com, and you can't.

Comment: What does `log out` even mean in a web site? HTTP is stateless after all, and browser request can come 10, 20 minutes apart. What logout really means is terminating the user's session on the site, eliminating any state data held for that session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not sign out all accounts, but you can sign out the user that was logged in to your application if that helps.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request

1. Configure the optional clame `login_hint` in the entra ID application.
2. Add the string from that claim as a paramter to the logout forward url `.../oauth2/v2.0/logout?logout_hint={login_hint}` to entra ID

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> To be truly signed out the user has to select the account that they want to sign out of. Is there anyway that I can extend my code above to bypass this screen and just log all accounts out that may be present.

Since this page is from Microsoft not your own web page, it's impossible you let you choose a way to logout out all the Microsoft account.